# Get data from php script using Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, web

I am trying to use some data calculated with a php script in javascript, this is my code :

```
<html>
<head>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="duplicate()"> button send</button>


        <script>
        function duplicate() 
            {   
                    var action = "CreationBoard";
                    alert(action);
                    $.ajax({
                        type : "POST",
                        url  : "file.php",
                        data : { action : action },
                        success: function(output) {
                            alert(output);
                        }
                    });
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

So I'm calling file.php to calculate my data :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['action']))
{
    $return = some_function($_POST['action']);
}
?>
```

I need to use $return in javascript, how to do that ?? I've seen many examples, but they only show how to send data with Ajax to php, not from php to ajax.
How should I do that ??

Comment: whatever is output from the php script is what will be in the `output` variable in javascript. So you just need to echo your return value or depending on what type of data the return value from `some_function` is maybe `echo json_encode($return)` (for example if was an array).

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['action']))
{
    $return = some_function($_POST['action']);
    echo $ return
}
?>
```

Javascript doesn't know php variable. All it know is the data returned

Comment: I tried this but I can't use output outside ajax, even if i use another variable, how can I use it ??

Answer (score 1):

In your file.php I would do

```
echo json_encode($return);
```

And then modify your ajax to expect a json return:

```
function duplicate() 
{   
        var action = "CreationBoard";
        alert(action);
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url  : "file.php",
            data : { action : action },
            dataType: 'json', 
            success: function(output) {
                alert(output);
            }
        });
}
```

the output variable that you have in your alert should look like your array and you can do with that what you want.

Comment: I tried this but I can't use output outside ajax, even if i use another variable, how can I use it ??

Comment: Normally you would just do what you need to do inside that ajax success. If you absolutely needed to do something with them outside of that you could always set a cookie inside that success and retrieve them in other parts of your code or you could write the values to a hidden div or form and retrieve them later. Both might be a little hacky but if you can I'd say try to do everything within the success function.